# Как получать одинаковые индексы и менять их местами?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Всем привет.
*Кратко о проекте:* Django-проект, есть элементы Item при добавлении каждого нового - создаётся order_index по порядку (+1 от общего числа), для сортировки.
Реализованы 2 функции: up_item которая прибавлеят +1 к order_index, и down_item которая отнимает -1 от order_index.

*Проблема:* Совпадение индексов order_item. Может получится несколько индексов, например, со значением 2.

Функция выглядит так:

```
def up_item(request, id):
    item = Item.objects.get(id=id)
    item.order_index +=1
    item.save()
    return redirect('/')
```

**Нужно: сделать так, чтобы индексы не повторялись (при добавлении +1, отнимался -1 у другого).
Чтоб при функции up_item прибавлялся +1 к order_index и отнимался -1 у order_index другого item с таким же значением индекса.
И при down_item отнимался -1, но прибавлялся +1 у item с таким же индексом order_index.**

**Например: item_bb имеет индекс 1, а item_cc имеет индекс 2.
При нажатии на функцию up_item - у обоих получится одинаковые индексы 2, и это проблема! Нужно чтоб функция не только прибавляля +1 у item_bb, но и отнимала -1 у item_cc!**

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`сделать так, чтобы индексы не повторялись` - поставить `unique` столбцу :)

`менять их местами` - что-то такое:

```py
def set_order_index(item: Item, distinction: int) -> None:
    items_to_swap = Item.objects.filter(
        order_index=item.order_index + distinction
    )
    if len(items_to_swap) > 0:
        item_to_swap = items_to_swap[0]
        item_to_swap.order_index = item.order_index
        item_to_swap.save()
    item.order_index += distinction
    item.save()


def up_item(request, id):
    item = Item.objects.get(id=id)
    set_order_index(item, 1)
    return redirect('/')
```

Для `down_item` вторым аргументом передавать `-1`. Также изначально не должно быть одинаковых индексов, существующие ошибки функция не правит.

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо!